# Vista Home Premium IIS 7.0 and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-vista

New laptop, new operating system. Windows Vista premium.

I've installed Visual Studio and IIS 7.0.

I open my web project in visual studio and vist the properties view for the web app.

The webDev server is currently selected.

I select IIS instead and I get the warning IIS telling me I need to install IIS 6.0 configuration compatability/meta base and windows authentication

All those are installed apart from windows authentication (which I am told is not supported for Vista Home Premium).

Is it possible to configure my web apps to run on IIS (I will also need debugging capability)

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on Windows Features on for IIS 6.0 configuration
Just go Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off.
In opened window choose which configuration is you want to configure your web application

[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture2]

For more information about IIS7 go to [IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/getstarted)